# Modification in journal3.2 view file with opencart events 4.0.2.2 version

Tags: php, mysql, events, themes, opencart

I am using opencartframework 4.0.2.2 and installed journal 3.2 theme. but some 3rd party module did not work in it. I am stuck to fix this issue  modify the journal view file for last days. I am using opencart events to modify it.

i am using following function to modify view file

protected function getTemplateBuffer( $route, $event_template_buffer )

$route is journal3/product/product
file is C:\XXXXXXX\catalog\view\theme\journal3\template\product\product.twig

PHP Notice:  Cannot find template file for route 'journal3/product/product'